# installing mysql server on a network

Tags: mysql, networking

I want to install MySQL server at work. The goal is to give Remote Access to different users. This part is OK. I have granted permission to others users and it worked.

My question is how and where can i install MySQL server so it is not depended on my work computer being on.  At my Works network we have common Networks harddisk. If i install MySQL server there, is it gonna be running all the time? or do i need to contact IT in order to install MySQL on the server hosting Our main work database?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of considerations to be made when installing new servers. If you are going to be running an `SQL Server` your I.T. Department should know about it. They are also going to be the best people to determine potential security concerns and where it would be most suitably hosted.

When you say you have "common Networks harddisk" I presume you mean a mapped network drive or SMB Shares. This is for data storage and you cannot install anything to there without direct access to the server they are running on.

It is also likely that your company is already running a dedicated `SQL Server` which you may be able to utilize.

Either way if you have an IT Department, They need to know and they are the only people who can answer this question.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to speed up the instalation process since i havent got help yet. I also thought that IT is concern about secure data transfer  and so on.

Comment: Hi, Hopefully IT are working on a solution for you in the background and they just have not updated you yet. Unfortunately things like this which can have an impact on infrastructure usually take a bit of time.